# Which Messenger service allows you to make voice calls with the least amount of bandwidth?

Tags: windows, software-rec, voip, instant-messaging, voice

I'll be going to a country side for a few days and the speeds there are pathetic!

Which voice messenger uses the least amount of bandwidth in order to make voice calls to other pc's.

*Speeds are a little better than dial-up nearly 80-100 kbps*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Skype should work fine](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA151/How-much-bandwidth-does-Skype-use-while-I-m-in-a-call)

> **How much bandwidth does Skype use while I'm in a call?**
>
> Skype automatically selects the best
>   codec depending on the connection
>   between yourself and the person you
>   are calling. On average, Skype uses
>   between **3-16 kilobytes/sec** depending
>   on bandwidth available for other
>   party, network conditions in between,
>   callers CPU performance, etc.

Comment: Just as a reference for other people who get confused with bits and bytes when they're being transferred rather than stored... http://www.mediaroad.com/products/speedcheck/free_tools/unit_convert/proc.php

Comment: Just used it last week on a poor connection and it was fine.  Latency will be the big challenge.

Comment: I tried using skype there before but it refuses to connect there, though browsing through websites seemed to be relatively good.